# split the elements in the array list

Tags: java

am trying to split elements in array list .
For example i have an arrayList like

```
List <String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
```

elements  `// ["frnec","fdct","logic","mastro","seloger"]`
The size of the elements should be dynamic...

```
 List<List<String>> splittedlists = null;
```

i want to split the elements like `["frnec"] ,["fdct",logic"],["mastro", "seloger"].`

```
splittedlists //[["frnec"] ,["fdct",logic"],["mastro", "seloger"]].
```

But the size of the new `splittedlists`  should not exceed 4 ,based on that i have to chop the `elements`

i had got lots of code code to split lists.But i dont know how to set the maximum size of the `'splittedlists'.`
but it will split by setting the target size of spitted elements

```
  public static <T extends Object> List<List<T>> split(List<T> list, int targetSize) {
        List<List<T>> lists = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += targetSize) {
            lists.add(list.subList(i, Math.min(i + targetSize, list.size())));
        }
        return lists;
    }
```

My requirmeent is to split elements in the list by setting the maximum array size(here `4`) of `splittedlists`

If elements are `// ["frnec","fdct"] i want to split is as ["frnec"], ["fdct"]`
if elements are `// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6]` i have to split without exceeding the new array size `4` like

```
 [[0,1],[2,3],[4,8],[6]]
```

Comment: Question doesn't include any code. (incidentally, the past tense of split is split)

Comment: Do the sublists need to maintain the same ordering as the original list?

Comment: @pvg a google of "splitted" on SO alone gives 212,000 results ;-)

Comment: @ringø heh, I'm sure 'stucked' does too, it's still wrong. They don't call them 'irregular verbs' for laughs although they do regularly confuse English learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer.. Guess you can understand what I'm doing..

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        list.add(i+"");
    }
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = list.size()/4;
    int y = list.size()%4;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i=j) {
        j = i+x;
        if(y>0){
            j++;
            y--;
        }
        lists.add(list.subList(i, j));
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(lists);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to maintain the order you can use modulus (`%`) operator. So for 3 sublists, it would put the 0th element in the 0th sublist, the first element in the first sublist, the second element in the second sublist, the third element in the 0th sublist, the fourth element in the 1st sublist.... etc.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++){
  listOfLists.get(i % 3).add(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: can u provide a sample code..i didnt get..also i can accept ur answer

Comment: yes i dont need to maintain the order...but the size of the split list shoulb nt exceed 4

Comment: getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 inplace of   listOfLists.get(i % 3).add(list.get(i));
}

Comment: @Psl you need to add some empty lists to `listOfLists` before you start.